# Can not Uninstall nodejs package

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I installed nodejs running this command :

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb 
sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```

but even after trying this :

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

it won't unistall

Comment: can you open a new terminal and try to use `node -v ` also , `where node`

Comment: `node -v` give `4.2.1` and `where node`  gives `-bash: where: command not found`

Comment: what about the other command?

Comment: `where` is not a bash command (zsh). you want `which` probably.

Comment: `which node` gives me this : `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that could help you:

- [How to remove node.js from Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04)
- [How to completely uninstall node.js from Ubuntu](http://To%20completely%20uninstall%20node%20js%20from%20Ubuntu)

You need to uninstall node.js, npm, all binaries, dependencies and other containers that are not located at one folder of your system.

**UPD**

Based on your comment that command `which node` returns `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node` I assume that you have also installed node.js v10.16.3 from user *pi* via Node Version Manager (*.nvm* folder). You can delete it by using this command:

> nvm uninstall v10.16.3

Source: [How to Install and Manage Node.js via NVM](https://tecadmin.net/install-nodejs-with-nvm/)

Comment: I am now trying to remove it from the path so that i reinstall it from the original site and then run it again ( unfortunately `nvm uninstall v10.16.3` just erased the original version ) i am alsto starting to consider `sudo rm -r /` as a possible option

Comment: @gamercodeman why is there a tag of raspberry Pi in your question???

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hungred.com/how-to/completely-removing-nodejs-npm/amp/